# What are good alternatives to "using namespace std;"?

Tags: c++, namespaces, std

I understand that `using namespace std;` is problematic (e.g. from reading the answers to ["Why is `using namespace std` considered bad practice?"](/q/1452721)).

What are good alternatives to importing the standard namespace like that?

I'd like to know what I can do to improve my code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've made an [edit] to your question to concentrate on the part for which I couldn't find an existing good answer.  It's quite a drastic edit, but I think it makes a question that can be reopened and useful.

Answer (score 6):

The main alternatives to bringing in *everything* from the `std` namespace into the global one with `using namespace std;` at global scope are:

1. Only bring in the actual names you need. For example just bring in `vector` with `using std::vector;`
2. Always use explicit namespace qualifications when you use a name. For example `std::vector<int> v;` (in *headers*, this should almost always be the only thing you do)
3. Bring in all names, but in a reduced scope (like only inside a function). For example `void f() { using namespace std; vector<int> v; }` - this does not pollute the global namespace.

Answer (score 2):

The alternative is to write `std::` everywhere. It's frowned upon because of name collisions and because it's unclear. If you just write `vector` I don't immediately know if you're using some math 3d vector or the standard library vector or something else. If you write `std::vector` it's clear. If you `using namespace std`, `vector` may collide with my own 3d math class called `vector`.

Comment: Hardly the only alternative..